# How will I enqueue an object before or after i save it to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a Queue Management system right now in ASP.NET MVC

1st scenario:
customer will go to a laptop, enter their name and then confirm to receive the queue number, then the data will be save to the database.
My question is how and where will I enqueue them? so that I can dequeue them later when the agent call them?

KiosksController:

```
public static Queue<Queue> todayQueue = new Queue<Queue>();
public ActionResult SetQueueInfo([Bind(Include = "QueueId,Name,QueueNumber,ServiceId,ServiceName,ServiceLetter")] Queue queue, int? id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Queues.Add(queue);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View(queue);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

2nd Scenario the Agent will click next then it will serve the next customer First in First out.
How can I dequeue them? here is my button of "Finish"

TellerScreenController

```
public static Queue<QueueTable> todayQueue;

    public ActionResult BtnNext()
    {
        var first = todayQueue.Dequeue();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some ideas about your requirement.

You need create a `Queue` (from System.Collections namespace) as static variable.

Add two action `Reverse()` and `Reset()`

When you add new item, you push to Queue and save to your DB

When you want to handle queue, you call `Dequeue()` to get first item from list also remove from Queue.

Because you use static variable for Queue, you need support a method reset Queue for next reserve.

```
private static Queue<QueueTable> todayQueue = new Queue<QueueTable>();

public ActionResult SetQueueInfo([Bind(Include = "QueueId,Name,QueueNumber,ServiceId,ServiceName,ServiceLetter")] QueueTable queue, int? id)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                todayQueue.Enqueue(queue);
                db.Queues.Add(queue);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View(queue);
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Reserve()
        {
            var first = todayQueue.Dequeue();

            // pass to view and handle it
            return View(first);
        }

        public ActionResult ResetQueue()
        {
            // reset queue after finish
            todayQueue = new Queue<QueueTable>();
        }
```

Display in cshtml

```
@model QueueTable

<p>@Model.QueueNumber</p>
```

Comment: Goodmorning @Hien Nguyen, just wanna ask. what if im going to dequeue it from the other page? how can I handle it?

Comment: Because you use the queue as static variable static Queue<QueueTable> todayQueue, you can dequeue it from other page.

Comment: don't need to reference it?

Comment: You should create a class and put static Queue<QueueTable> todayQueue in that class and use anywhere.

Comment: can you show me the proper way? and i need to render the dequeued item in my view

Comment: i still can't dequeue it from another page, when I hit the button the todayQueue becomes null.